# ошибка "You have an error in your SQL syntax" при выполнении MySQL скрипта в php

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

пытаюсь выполнить через ajax код:

```
$connection = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);
function queryMysql($query)
{
    global $connection;
    $result = $connection->query($query);
    if (!$result) die($connection->error);
    return $result;
}

function shieldString($string)
{
    $string = preg_replace ("/^[^a-zA-ZА-Яа-я0-9\s]*$/","",$string);
    return $string;
}

$email = preg_replace ("/^[^a-zA-ZА-Яа-я0-9@\s]*$/","",$_POST["email"]);
$name = shieldString($_POST["name"]);
$surname = shieldString($_POST["surname"]);
$pass = md5($_POST["password"]);
$query = "INSERT INTO 'users' (
    'user_id', 'user_status', 'user_email', 'user_pass', 'user_name', 'user_surname', 'user_avatar')
    VALUES (NULL, '2', " . $email . ", " . $pass . ", " . $name . ", " . $surname . ", '/front/img/users/user.png');";
queryMysql($query);
```

при выполнении выводится следующая ошибка:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version  for the right syntax to use
>   near '@mail.ru, e10adc3949ba59abbe56e057f20f883e, Николай, Ф�' at line
>   3

Но ведь синтаксис не нарушен, вместо буквы "е" выводится непонятный символ.
В чем причина такой ошибки?

Comment: Нарушен, потому что строку в кавычки не берете. И вообще тут зеленый свет SQL-инъекциям.

Comment: @Etki строку какую? И не подскажите аналог mysqli_real_escape_string?

Comment: Вы передаете строковые параметры в values, беря в кавычки только "2". Все остальное передается как есть и воспринимается парсером как языковые конструкции вместо строк.

Comment: @Etki точно же.. а как себя от инъекций обезопасить? mysql_real_escape_string в данном случае не могу понять, как использовать. Он мне возвращает пустую строку

Comment: использовать PDO и подготовленные выражения

Comment: UNION DROP TABLE users =)